# C# GetOleDbSchemaTable. Name of first Excel Worksheet and its columns

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

```
            try
            {
                string connectionString = string.Empty;

                if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
                        ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Print(connectionString);
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), fileName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                    //connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), fileName) + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";
                }

                OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Open();

                //connection.Get
                DataTable dtSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            }
```

connection.Open() seems to be connecting just fine. Now I have gotten a dtSchema Data Table object. I am needing to get the name of the Excel worksheet or worksheets that were gotten if any. I am also scanning the object to find out where the column names are. There is supposed to be some columns in the schema. Is it documented where the columns are?
When I do some output in my immediate window:

```
dtSchema.Columns[0].ToString()
"TABLE_CATALOG"
dtSchema.Columns[1].ToString()
"TABLE_SCHEMA"
dtSchema.Columns[2].ToString()
"TABLE_NAME"
dtSchema.Columns[3].ToString()
"TABLE_TYPE"
```

These are not the column names of the first worksheet, which is what I am looking for mainly the name of the first worksheet and its columns.

Thank you for posting..

Comment: one suggestion to use `if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() == ".xlsx")` instead of `if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == ".xlsx")`. This would handle both `example.XLXS` and `example.xlxs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look for column names. See the resultant **COLUMN_NAME** column

```
 DataTable dtCols = this.connection.GetSchema("Columns");
```

**TABLE_NAME** is also helpful for your case to identify the Sheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hassan. I really like the image of the visualizer.